# How do I properly detect game objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My goal is to write one script that I can use on different game objects and it should have specific variables tied to it on that game object only without affecting other scripts in the process.

For example, if I take this script and put it on two game objects each game object should have their own unique variable value in that same script.

If my question is not clear enough, I'm more than happy to elaborate further.

I have a good understanding of the Unity Editor, however, I'm pretty new to C# so I don't think it's unreasonable that I made a rookie mistake somewhere in my code.

The way I've got things setup is that I have two separate scripts:

- `Fighting` controls the values like the `Team`, `Health`, `Attack Damage`, `Cool Down`, `Cooling down` and `Snap`
- `TrigDetect` controls the detection of a trigger being activated as a result of an enemy entering the trigger radius.

The problem I'm currently having lies in the `TrigDetect` script I guess.

It should also be noted that an empty attached to each game object in question contains both of these scripts and is tagged as "Troop".

**TrigDetect**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TrigDetect : MonoBehaviour
{
    //public GameObject[] Enemy;
    bool once = false; 

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Troop"))
        {
            //Debug.Log("Entered");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Troop"))
        {
            //Debug.Log("Exitted");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Troop"))
        {

            Fighting self = GetComponent<Fighting>();

            GameObject g = GameObject.Find("Detection");

            Fighting fScript = g.GetComponent<Fighting>();

            //Enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Troop");
            //Debug.Log("Staying");
            //Debug.Log(Enemy);
            //Debug.Log(self.Health);
            //Debug.Log(fScript.Health);

            if (once == false)
            {
                Debug.Log("I am the team:" + self.Team);
                Debug.Log("I have detected the team:" + fScript.Team);
                once = true;
            }

            if (self.Team != fScript.Team)
            {

                if (self.CoolingDown == false)
                {
                    self.CoolingDown = true;
                    fScript.Health -= self.AttackDamage;
                }

                else
                {
                    self.CoolDown -= Time.deltaTime;
                    if (self.CoolDown <= 0)
                    {
                        self.CoolingDown = false;
                        self.CoolDown = self.original;
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

**Fighting**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fighting : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int Team = 1;
    public int Health = 100;
    public int AttackDamage = 10;
    public float CoolDown = 2;
    public float original = 2;
    public bool CoolingDown = false;
    public bool Snap = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Snap == true || Health <= 0)
        {
            //Destroy(gameObject, .5f);
            Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.N)) Instantiate(transform.parent.gameObject);
    }
}
```

The expected result when I move one game object into the trigger radius of the other is that they should **both** start subtracting `Health` from each other based on the `AttackDamage` value. They should do this every time the `CoolingDown` value is false. When an attack is executed, it's flipped to `true` and a timer starts, when the timer is done it's flipped back to `false`.

However, upon moving the two objects into each other's radius', the first object has its health taken away as expected and then proceeds to do nothing until it's health reaches `0` then it dies because of the object attacking it. The object attacking is successfully attacking the other object but, is still not being affected by the object it's attacking.

Comment: Every instance of a MonoBehaviour is unique to the object it's attached to.  Are you sure *both* of your GameObjects tagged as `Troop`?

Comment: Yes. All GameObjects that need to be affected by this have a child empty that contains both scripts and the empty is tagged as "Troop". Feel free to grab this code and recreate my setup in unity to see the odd behavior for yourself. :)

Comment: What is the "Detection" object you're finding in your `OnStay`?

Comment: That's what I labeled the empty that holds both of the scripts. This empty is the child of both objects.

Comment: You said `have a child empty that contains both scripts and the empty is tagged as "Troop".` .. does this empty object also carry all `Colliders` or are both parent objects also tagged as `Troop`?

Comment: Also `what I labeled the empty that holds both of the scripts. This empty is the child of both objects` that makes no sense .. an object can only be child of one parent object. If the object is the holder of the script there is no need to call `Find` you can access it by simply using `gameObject`. However you should get your own component already in `Awake` and store the reference. That's more efficient and less confusing than your current code

Comment: The parent objects are untagged and have their own collider which is not marked as a trigger so that they can move around the environment. The empty object has its own collider marked as a trigger so it can detect when another empty object labeled "Detection" comes within its range and vise versa for the other empty that entered it. So in other words, they should both correctly detect each other when in range of each other in this situation and react accordingly.

Comment: I also kinda misworded that. There is one empty object per parent. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: As for the reason I use find, It's so that when the object goes in range of the other, they can both modify the other's health values to decrease by their own attack damage if that makes any sense.

Comment: So I guess: when you do `Find` it finds the **same** object on both scripts .. namely the first in the hierarchy .. so on of of the two scripts you find your own empty object and skip the rest in `if(self.Team != FScript.Team)` .. you should try to use `other.Find("Detection");` instead, however there are a lot of things that can be improved so maybe I'll post an answer later when I'm on a PC ;)

Comment: That's basically what's happening to the best of my knowledge. Thank you for being helpful and patient with me. I'll be looking forward to more help with this. :)

Comment: is the cooldown for your attack or is it for you taking damage?

Comment: The cooldown is for the attack so it executes the code every amount of seconds I set it to. Also the "Original" is there to reset it back to what it was originally. I was planning to have this not be a public variable and just have it work in the background by changing itself to what the CoolDown is at the beginning of the script but, for some reason, C# didn't like that so I just made a quick work around.

Comment: @derHugo has it correct.  Your `Find` is finding the first instance in the scene of any object called "Detection", which is almost guaranteed to **never** be the one you actually want.  You don't need to do this as the OnTriggerStay *gives* you the other object object (via the collider).  I'll write a proper answer in a bit...

Comment: Many thanks for pointing this out @Immersive I'll be looking forward to seeing how it's properly done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, `Find(name)` only returns the first instance of anything by that name, thus your `g = Find(name)` is almost guaranteed to **never** be the object related to your trigger/collision condition.  The `OnTriggerStay(Collider other)` already gives you the 'other' collider that's in your trigger zone, so use it. :)

Replace this:

```
    GameObject g = GameObject.Find("Detection");
    Fighting fScript = g.GetComponent<Fighting>();
```

with this:

```
    Fighting fScript = other.GetComponent<Fighting>();
```

Comment: Oh my lord. I can't believe that's all it took and my issue was instantly fixed. A million thanks to you and @derHugo for being so helpful and patient with me. I'll still be looking forward to ways I can improve and optimize my code by the way.

Answer (score 2):

To your question header:

Every instaced (non-static) value is allways unique to the according component and thereby to the according `GameObject` it is attached to. You might want to refrase the question because this is actually not your issue.

The problem is that when you do

```
GameObject.Find("Detection");
```

it actually finds the **same** object both times: Namely the first one in the hierarchy. So in one of of the two components you find your own empty object and skip the rest in

```
if(self.Team != FScript.Team)
```

.. you could try to use

```
other.Find("Detection");
```

instead to only search in the according context .. However, you should **not** use `Find` at all!

1. It is very performance intense
2. You should allways reuse references and not search them over and over again
3. You don't need it in your case

   Since you say both scripts are attached to the same object you can simply use

   ```
   GetComponent<Fighting>();
   ```

   and you can do so already in `Awake` and reuse the reference instead:

   ```
   private Fighting myFighting;

   private void Awake()
   {
       myFighting = GetComponent<Fighting>();
   }
   ```

Than for the collision you don't have to use `Find` either because you already have the reference of the object you collide with: `other.gameObject`. I don't know your entire setup but you can search for the component either downwards in the hierachy

```
// the flag true is sued to also find inactive gameObjects and components
// leave it without parameters if you don't want this
var otherFighting = other.GetComponentInChildren<Fighting>(true);
```

or searcg upwards in the hierachy

```
var otherFighting = other.GetComponentInParent<Fighting>(true);
```

or if you already know you collide exactly with the correct GameObject anyway simply use

```
var otherFighting = other.GetComponent<Fighting>();
```

I will use the latter in my example.

Than cheking the health all the time in `Update` is a huge perfomance issue. You should rather have a method e.g. `TakeDamage` and do your check only if your health is actually changed:

**Fighting**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Fighting : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public int Team = 1;
    public int Health = 100;
    public int AttackDamage = 10;
    public float CoolDown = 2;
    public float original = 2;

    // you don't need that flag see below
    //public bool CoolingDown = false;
    public bool Snap = false;

    private void Update()
    {
        // you might also put this in a callback instead of update at some point later
        if(Snap == true)
        {
            Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject);
        }

        // Note: this also makes not muh sense because if you destroyed
        // the parent than you cannot instantiate it again!
        // use a prefab instead
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.N)) Instantiate(transform.parent.gameObject);
    }

    public void TakeDamge(int DamageAmount)
    {
        Health -= DamageAmount;

        if (Health > 0) return;

        Destroy(transform.parent.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Another performance issue in general: Even if `Start`, `Update` etc are empty, if they are present in your script Unity will call them. So if you don't use them then completely remove them to avoid that useless overhead.

So I would have

**TrigDetect**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TrigDetect : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool once = false; 

    private Fighting myFighting;

    private void Awake()
    {
        myFighting = GetComponent<Fighting>();
    }

    void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        // if wrong tag do nothing
        if (!other.CompareTag("Troop")) return;

        Fighting fScript = other.GetComponent<Fighting>();

        // here you should add a check
        if(!fScript)
        {
            // By using the other.gameObject as context you can find with which object
            // you collided exactly by clicking on the Log
            Debug.LogError("Something went wrong: Could not get the Fighting component of other", other.gameObject);
        }

        if (!once)
        {
            Debug.Log("I am the team:" + self.Team);
            Debug.Log("I have detected the team:" + fScript.Team);
            once = true;
        }

        // if same team do nothing
        if (self.Team == fScript.Team) return;

        // you don't need the CoolingDown bool at all:
        self.CoolDown -= Time.deltaTime;

        // if still cooling down do nothing
        if(self.CoolDown > 0) return;

        fScript.TakeDamage(self.AttackDamage);
        self.CoolDown = self.original;
    }
}
```

Comment: Points for improvements =)

Comment: Don't feel bad @derHugo you were a giant help too and I'll still be using your improvements as well so nothing will go to waste. :)